# WCF with window mobile 6

Tags: windows-mobile-6

I am a new to this technology. Can anyone instruct me how to integrate a WCF with windows mobile 6 using .net framework 3.5? i need work example with step by step please dont provide me any link.

Answer (score 0):

Here in article on using using the Mobile WCF.
[Write an IM App with the .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx)

The code is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164255.aspx

There are lot's of articles on the Google search for 'WCF on windows mobile', but this one looks like the best into.